# Why GCM Notification Delayed and Some times Its Not showing in statusbar?

Tags: android, push-notification

I have developed an app And I used GCM for push notification.But in my app some times notification receiving,some times its delay to receive and some times it will not receive notification.

Answer (score 2):

GCM (Google Cloud Messageing) It's not a perfect solution to do work, When a third party server send to request to Google server for push-notification to mobile. After that a Google server is responsible for send push-notification to mobile. Mostly time Google server sent notification immediately. Sometimes it's delay just because of network traffic.

Suppose Google server sent notification to device now developer responsibility to handle the request and show the notification on notification.

## Failure Case (Device side):

1) No Network - If Google server sent notification to your device
2) Slow Network 
3) Wrong way to handling message

As per your above explanation, you are getting message sometimes that means your code is well!

## If you performing some task after getting notification---Please choose other solution because you cann't believe on GCM.

Answer (score 0):

That mainly depends on internet speed. Also at times google server cant process the request.
If you received  the notification once that proves it will work

Answer (score 0):

Check your code or server-side code.
(also more important network service or google background service)

in my case,

my GCM service success rate is 65% (google statistics)

but I remove 'collapseKey'(in the online sample code) then success rate up to 85%

important is GCM isn't 100% success services. (this is google say..)

finally, this link will help you

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html